# Changing order status to "processing" via API makes really capture order in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have a tiny question about Magento API (SOAP V1)

Suppose current order status is just "pending",

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'sales_order.addComment', array('orderIncrementId' => '100000001', 'status' => 'processing'));
```

This code makes really "pending" order to "processing"? (with creating invoice or credit-card -capturing?)

Otherwise, is there any method which can really do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not change order state with magento api. So you should create invoice.

[see here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderInvoice/sales_order_invoice.create.html)